# Recover unsaved word document that was opened directly from Outlook with temp/cache files without using asd files

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, file-recovery, hard-drive-cache

The title sounds a bit complicated, so I'll briefly explain how my problem came about. I have received a Word document by email which I should edit. I opened the file, without saving it, just directly from Outlook.

After I deactivated the write protection, I started to write. I would normally always enable the autoupload feature to my OneDrive cloud. I don't know why I did that either. Today an automatic Windows update went off and my unsaved Word file is gone and unrecoverable. The file was not saved, so I could only open the file that was sent to me by email. No ASD file was saved, therefore no version history.There is no ASD file and no other way to reopen it through Word itself. I read online that by temp files, which are created by Word or Windows every 10 minutes, you can recover the document.

I have looked through the temp folder and sorted by timestamp. Currently I have found these files for today.

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp

[All temp Files from today](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH4UN.jpg)

I opened the file I marked with the name "prep__Program Files_Microsoft Office..." with Word and a window opened

[Word opens up with this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCleX.jpg)

The file opened but it was not possible to read it out, because only unknown characters were visible. The funny thing is that exactly the same page number was visible when the file shut down because of the Windows update. So I think I found the right file.

I've been searching online for several hours now for a solution to the problem and haven't gotten any usable results, so this is my last chance.

My Questions are:

- Are there ways to decode these temp/cache files, so i can extract everything i've lost?
- Are there any other ways to recover my word document?

Comment: It is always a bad idea to open a Word file for editing directly from email. Much better practice is to save the attachment to the computer and open it from there. Here is a web page that addresses the problem and possible ways to recover lost changes. **How to recover lost email attachments from Outlook** by Graham Mayor, Word MVP http://www.gmayor.com/outlook_attachments.htm

Comment: @CharlesKenyon sadly the Problem mentioned in your link doesn't match with my problem